# Is it possible to send data and files in the same request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I have an API that receives uploads of APP files and images

To send from APP to the API I use **fetch**

```
const data = new FormData();
let i = 0;

export const dataPush = (fileUri, fileType, fileName) => {

  data.append('file'+i, {
    uri: fileUri,
    type: fileType, 
    name: fileName
  });

  i++;
};

export const uploadFiles = () => {

  console.log(data);

  fetch('http://192.168.0.23/apiapp/public/api/annex', {
    method: 'post',
    body: data
  }).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  });

}
```

But I'd like to send in the same request data obtained from a form

But I did not find a way to do it, always or just send the data, or just send the files

Is it possible to send everything in the same request? And if possible, how?

Comment: You can't just append a plain object onto a FormData instance, it will just be sent as the text `[Object object]` as it will try to covert the appended item to a string if it is not a blob/file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just append whatever data that you desire that isn't file data to the FormData object.

```
data.append("not_a_file", "This is a string");
```

Answer (score 0):

I did so based on Quentin's response and it worked

```
const formData = new FormData();
const i = 0;

export const filePush = (fileUri, fileType, fileName) => {

  formData.append('file'+i, {
    uri: fileUri,
    type: fileType, 
    name: fileName
  });

  i++;
};

export const dataPush = (name, content) => {

  formData.append(name, content);

};

export const uploadFiles = () => {

  fetch('http://192.168.0.23/apiapp/public/api/annex', {
    method: 'post',
    body: formData
  }).then(res => {
    console.log(res._bodyText)
  }).catch(error => { 
    console.log(error.message)
  });

}
```